# Is it a good idea to install ubuntu server on Raspberry Pi Zero W?

Tags: server, raspberrypi

I'm working on a vibration analysis project, the goal is to send vibrations using the accelerometer sensor to a remote server.

Is it a good idea to install ubuntu server especially that I will need only to:

- Wifi connection
- Accelerometer API
- Send data to the remote server every X minutes using python script (cron job)

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems quite a simple task and I would guess the hardware can handle it.  However I would probably stick with a recent Raspbian (I guess they call it Raspberry Pi OS now?) unless you have lots of experience with running third-party OS's on the platform, or just want to learn how.  Most of the public info out there (and there is LOTS) assumes you're running some flavor of Raspbian.

I will tell you from experience that when the WiFi is doing lots of I/O, it eats the CPU (there is just one core) and the Zero will fall on its face pretty quickly.  They are great, as long as you don't ask too much of them...

Comment: Thanks @AgentSmith for this comment. Do you think that BANANA PI ZERO could  be better  ?

Comment: The hardware surely is much better.  I have never used one.  The question is, how good is the software support for it?  Some boards don't have a great software environment or community to ask questions, which can make it difficult to get your OS/application working well.  I don't know if this is a concern for the Banana Pi Zero, or not.  It looks interesting though.